# How to map doctrine entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I want to adapt my folder structure to something similar:

```
app 
└─── ...
bin 
└─── ...    
src
└───MyNamespace
    ├───Application
    │   ├───Controller
    │   │   └───UserController.php      
    │   ├───Entity
    │   │   └───User
    │   │       ├───User.php
    │   │       └───UserFactory.php
vendor 
└─── ...        
web 
└─── ...
```

my config.yml file in the orm section looks like:

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    auto_mapping: false
    mappings:
        user:
          type:      php
          dir:       %kernel.root_dir%/../src/MyNamespace/Application/Entity/User/User
          prefix:    MyNamespace\Application\Entity\User\User
          alias:     User
          is_bundle: false
```

and my User.php file starts with:

```
namespace MyNamespace\Application\Entity\User;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
...
}
```

And then I get the:

InvalidArgumentException: Specified non-existing directory "C:/www/myapp/app/../src/MyNamespace/Application/Entity/User/User" as Doctrine mapping source.

Btw, I'm using the Symfony2 framework.

Comment: Read the error message then consider what dir is probably an abbreviation of.

Comment: IIRC, you can't have sub folders in the Entity directory.

Answer (score 5):

Grimv01k gave me the hint, but the final working solution were in the config.yml file with:

```
mappings:
    user:
        type: annotation
        dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/MyNamespace/Application/Model/User
        alias: 'User'
        prefix: MyNamespace\Application\Model\User
        is_bundle: false
```

that's it. If I didn't change the mapping type to annotation, I've had the error "No mapping file found named 'MyNamespace.Application.Entity.User.User.php'" even having this file in my folder project structure. Still I didn't understand it, but it works now. Noob days... :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've got `Entity` out of bundles, and config points only to entities source, like this:

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    auto_mapping: false
    mappings:
        user:
          type:      php
          dir:       %kernel.root_dir%/../src/MyNamespace/Application/Entity
          prefix:    MyNamespace\Application\Entity
          alias:     Entity
          is_bundle: false
```

`Entity` dir should be a directory, so try to change `dir`, `prefix` and `alias` settings. And than you actually can put subfolder `User` in it and work with it by namespace.

By the way, you can read a great [article](http://elnur.pro/symfony-without-bundles/) about `Symfony` structure customization.